# Disk recognized in docking station but not external enclosure

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

I run Windows 10. I have a new 16TB Seagate Exos disk which works when in an Orico docking station but not when placed in any other external enclosure (I've tried two different WD My Book Duo enclosures and one cheap no-name one). All enclosures and the docking station are USB 3.0.

Initially I wanted to house it in one of the My Book Duos but in that enclosure Windows wouldn't format the disk. Disk Management could see the disk and said it needed to be initialized but when I tried it said 'Invalid Function'. I experimented with different enclosures with no success but eventually resorted to the Orico docking station and in that I was able to format it, create a 4TB partition, name the partition and read and write to it. All seemed fine but when I tried to put it back in the My Book Duo, Disk Management could only see an unformatted uninitialized disk. I tried AOMEI Partition Assistant and Disk Drill with the same result: both see the disk but not NTFS or the partition. When installed in the Orico, the disk looks perfectly normal in both Disk Drill and Partition Assistant.

I've run the Seagate disk tool and it thinks the disk is fine.

Any thoughts? Let me know if there is any additional information that would help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: What exact model is your WD My Book Duo?

Comment: It is the diskless model that they sell. Box has no model number dsignation on it. It simply says 'My Book Duo. Massve Capacity. High Speed. Hardware RAID.'

Comment: Is it advertised as 16 TB?

Comment: There is no mention of disk size on the box or in the documentation that comes with it.  The WD website says that the My Book Duo has capacity 'up to 36TB'. Also, the cheap no name SATA enclosure I have has 'Fits any SATA disk' on it and the disk doesn't work properly in it either.

Comment: I asked, since I have seen advertised several models of WD My Book Duo, each one labelled with a different maximum capacity. Have you tried asking Seagate Support and/or WD Support?

Comment: I've tried WD support. They did at least respond but the response was of the 'first thing that came into their head to make me go away' variety.

Comment: I must admit I'm beginning to think I'll just have to accept that the Orico dock is just the way I'll have to use this disk. All I can think of is to buy an Orico disk enclosure and hope whatever it is that makes the docking station work with this disk is carried over into their enclosure products. I guess I should try Seagate but to be honest I'm doubtful it will help. Their disk works in docking station and shows as 100% fine in their disk analysis tool.